# Allow a Web User to Create a New .Net Page in the Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to allow a user to create a new .aspx page from a web interface. So, for example, say I was building a wiki site and wanted to allow a user to add an article on how helpful stackoverflow is. Is it possible to create a new .aspx page from a master page and then allow the user to add content to it? Also, it is possible to allow users to delete pages form a VS project?

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: this is not a wise idea. have a single page handle the requests and generates the content.

Comment: It's possible.  But it's a lot simpler to get a Content Management System.  DotNetNuke is a free one, and there are plenty of  others to choose from.  http://webmasterformat.com/blog/top-asp-net-cmss

Comment: Any reason to re-invent the wheel?  There's many frameworks that do exactly that sort of thing..

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to give DotNetNuke a try and see if it will work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try content management systems, like:

- WordPress
- Joomla
- DotNetNuke

or others.

Comment: Just adding to this, check out http://webmasterformat.com/blog/top-asp-net-cmss  There are a number of CMS's available for .net with varying degrees of complexity and usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

if you install DotNetNuke (dnn), it wil be possible to have pages that look like: mydomain.com/wiki/mynewpage.aspx

But you might be better of using the DNN wiki module (or an article module) to allow the user to enter content (based on his/her user rights). These modules are espacially tailored at the task at hand.